# Yasnippet (0.6.1c and 0.8) seems to "hide" autocomoplete (1.3.1) help in emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, redhat, yasnippet

I'm trying to use Yasnippet and Autocomplete Mode in Emacs 24.1 (built from sources) on a RHEL5. Here is my .emacs.d/init.el:

```
;; yasnippet
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas/initialize)
(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets")

;; auto-complete mode
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete-1.3.1")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete-1.3.1/dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

In this way, autocomplete doesn't show any help at all. If I remove the whole yasnippet stuff, it is *almost* ok (in the sense that help is shown for `load-path` but not for `defun`... but this is not the major issue right now). I tried also with Yasnippet 0.8 but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.cx4a.org/pub/auto-complete-yasnippet.el) solution.

P.S. That was stolen from the [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) recipes.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine for yasnippet 0.6.1 (but it doesn't work at all for version 0.8).

Comment: Update: it works fine _sometimes_. Really strange and annoying. The whole afternoon went away trying to fix this issue (without any success, of course).